# I am having an issue with babel building angular app for production

Tags: babeljs

Current Behavior
I am building my angular project on circleci and it just keeps failing with the following message:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
> '@babel/compat-data/corejs3-shipped-proposals'

Require stack:

```
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/polyfills/corejs3/usage-plugin.js
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/process-bundle.js
/home/circleci/eleven-app/frontend/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
```

I am using

```json
{
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.8.3",
  "core-js": "3.2.1",
  "tslib": "^1.11.1",
  "@babel/compat-data": "~7.8.0",
  "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.9.2",
  "ts-node": "7.0.0",
  "tslint": "5.11.0",
  "typescript": "3.5.3",
}
resolutions: {
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7"
}
```

here is npx nls why @babel/preset-env output:

```
eleven-app-frontend > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env@7.8.7
eleven-app-frontend > @nrwl/angular > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor > @babel/preset-env@7.9.5
eleven-app-frontend > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor > @babel/preset-env@7.9.5
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue today, so I'm assuming there's something weird with the latest version.

My package.json had the following:

```
"@babel/compat-data": "~7.9.0"
```

I removed the ~ to force 7.9.0 instead of allowing newer ones and it did the trick for me.

There's probably a newer version that works but since you opened an issue for them (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11427) I'll just wait for more details.

Comment: I'm looking into the same issue, it's strange because that library nor `@babel/runtime-corejs3` hasn't been published in weeks

Comment: @FaridGarciayala in my case I had to declare and use 7.9.0 which fixed the problem

Comment: @FaridGarciayala it should work (7.8/7.9) but try deleting "node_modules" before

Comment: Same issue today. Issue is only in build server, not on clean installs locally...

Answer (score 8):

I've the same issue when using TravisCI & Vue with Jest and Babel. My test suit has been failing. Adding `"@babel/compat-data": "7.9.0"` to **devDependencies** in my **package.json** file solved my problems.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to fix my failing test suite on CI.

Answer (score 8):

These 3 options we came up with so far:

- Adapt dependency of babel/preset-env to v7.9.0: `"@babel/preset-env": "=7.9.0"`
- In case you use a NodeJS Docker Image, fix the version to something below 13.13, i.e.: `node:13.12.0-alpine`
- Adding or upgrading `"@babel/compat-data": "7.9.0"` to devDependencies

The solutions are temporarily and should be removed as soon as there is an actual fix of the node images or the babel/preset-env library.

Linked Github issues:

babel - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11427

nodejs - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32852#issuecomment-613652057

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today in Github Actions build for a Vue FE project. It builds fine locally. I'm going to try the solution above and I'll report back...

*Update:* After looking through the package-lock file, my solution was to explicitly add "@babel/compat-data" to the prod dependencies. Previously it was only a dependency for some dev dependencies. So my package.json now looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.6",
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Same issue.
Solved it by following above advices + removing node_modules (see [this](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10477#issuecomment-618040636) github thread):

- Added explicitly `@babel/compat-data": "7.9.0"` to devDependencies
- Upgraded node (13.3 to 14.0 in my case)
- Had to **remove my node_modules folder** and re run `yarn` (or npm)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `yarn`, try to remove the `yarn.lock` file in your project. And then reinstall by run `yarn install`; you'll get a new `yarn.lock` file, which is fine.

It worked for me in my Next.js project.

Comment: thanks, and now my installed version @babel/compat-data is  `7.12.7`, besides, the  `yarn.lock` file changed a lot,